# html list <ol> breaking when user presses enter

Tags: html

i have a contenteditable div element which contains a list using `<ol>`. If the user selects somewhere else that is not a `<li>` then a new `<li>` item is not created. If the user presses enter twice after creating a list then no `<li>` item is created.

how do i force all lines in my div element to be a `<li>` item?

i dont have a fiddle account but if you add the contenteditable tag to the example here you can see/test it in action http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_lists

Comment: Please phrase your question properly and also add more description along with a fiddle if necessary. I do not understand what you are saying.

Comment: add some html code here?

Comment: may be it has something to do with javascript instead of html

Comment: Thanks for updating your question, now I understand but need to see your code to find out what is wrong. Can you put your code into fiddle and share with us. It is not necessary to have a fiddle account :)

Comment: wow my mistake guys! contenteditable tag was on my div element and not my list tag! thankyou for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The effect of `contenteditable` varies by browser, but the behavior described in the question is common when a list is inside an editable area, rather than declared as editable as an element. The reason appears to be that since the enclosing element is editable, the implementors thought that there should be a way to get out of the list, e.g. to add content after it.

If you change a single contenteditable block like

```
<div contenteditable>
some stuff
<ol><li>test</li></ol>
some other stuff
</div>
```

to three such blocks,

```
<div contenteditable>
some stuff
</div>
<ol contenteditable><li>test</li></ol>
<div contenteditable>
some other stuff
</div>
```

then the behavior changes: hitting Enter twice in the list just adds an empty item there.

But there is a problem with `<ol contenteditable>`: it seems to make IE 9 omit the list number (or for `ul` the list bullet), with no apparent way to make it put there. (Edit: This only happens in Quirks Mode. But this bug may be present in earlier IE versions in different modes. I recommend using `contenteditable` on a wrapper element rather than list elements like `ol` directly.)